# Setter only does assignment, yet declares that it throws a ParseException; in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, setter, throws

Discovered a `Date` setter that only does the typical assignment, yet has a `throws ParseException` for what seems like no good reason. No `Date` construction is happening in the body of the setter. Just assignment.

This is on a Hibernate entity. The setters field is annotated with @Column as nullable, insertable, and updateable. Not sure if that matters.

Is this obviously wrong and should be fixed by removing the `throws` or is there more research to do before deciding to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds perfectly safe to remove the throws declaration. A guess would be that the setter originally took a `String` and parsed it. If you have source control, a check in the history might confirm this.